# UNIX(AIX) - $? is always zero when executed a unix command inside system() call

Tags: shell, unix, aix

Out large unix application, executes a shell script using system() call. But before invoking system() it does a lot. But i don't know because it is a large application. But inside i want to check the return code of a shell command using $?. This check always succeed. For example ls  returns 0.

When the shell script is executed, it returns non-zero code. Only it does not work when the script is executed inside the application.

any help is really appreciated.

Comment: This is too board. We need an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck.

Comment: Is your large application written in C, Java, Perl, Whatever? The OK return value of the call to `system()` will say that the command has been passed to the shell and the shell has done something. When you want the shell return code and not the system() return value, you should try something else like calling a script that will exit with en echo of `$?`.